# how keep the hover enabled while the submenu is open

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover, submenu

I have a simple table on my website listing devices and their characteristics (in the example at the link below there will be a shortened version of the table).

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SubMenu } from "./SubMenu";

const subMenuSlice = <SubMenu />;

const nodes = [
  {
    id: "0",
    name: "Samsung Galaxy",
    subMenu: subMenuSlice
  },
  {
    id: "0",
    name: "Iphone",
    subMenu: subMenuSlice
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {nodes.map((val, key) => (
          <tr key={key}>
            <td>{val.name}</td>
            <td>{val.subMenu}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

SubMenu.tsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import AppsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Apps";
import * as DropdownMenu from "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu";
import "./styles.css";

export const SubMenu = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <DropdownMenu.Root open={isOpen} onOpenChange={setIsOpen}>
      <DropdownMenu.Trigger>
        <AppsIcon className="sss" />
      </DropdownMenu.Trigger>
      <DropdownMenu.Portal>
        <DropdownMenu.Content
          side="bottom"
          sideOffset={-30}
          align="start"
          alignOffset={80}
        >
          <button className="style-button">Edit </button>
          <button className="style-button">Make </button>
          <button className="style-button">Delete </button>
        </DropdownMenu.Content>
      </DropdownMenu.Portal>
    </DropdownMenu.Root>
  );
};
```

styles.css

```
    .sss {
  visibility: hidden;
}

tr:hover .sss {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
}

tr:hover {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: initial !important;
}

.style-button:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-rgb-5t7xkq

As you can see, when you hover over any of the lines, the entire line turns gray and an additional button appears. By clicking on this button the user gets a submenu.

Description of the problem: the problem is that when the user moves the cursor to the submenu, the hover (gray) disappears from the table row. Please tell me how to keep the hover enabled while the submenu is active (open)

Comment: Provide us your CSS code in order to get into a solution asap

Comment: @Zak You can see the full code at the link in my question

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem", where it says, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so— **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS."

Comment: I reckon this is an easy fix but without a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can't test or demo a solution.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I understand your requirements. Thank you

Comment: @Moob I have edited. Please, take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep track of some state, for example the current `id` of the item that is being "hovered". Then for that item add an extra class and style it depending on that class, in your example:

**App.tsx**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SubMenu } from "./SubMenu";
import { useState } from "react";

const subMenuSlice = <SubMenu />;

const nodes = [
  {
    id: "0",
    name: "Samsung Galaxy",
    subMenu: subMenuSlice
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Iphone",
    subMenu: subMenuSlice
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(null);

  const handleMouseEnter = (id) => {
    setIsHovered(id);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(null);
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {nodes.map((val, key) => (
          <tr
            key={key}
            onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(val.id)}
            onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
            className={val.id === isHovered ? "hovered" : ""} // here you set the class if the id matches. 
          >
            <td>{val.name}</td>
            <td>{val.subMenu}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.sss {
  visibility: hidden;
}

tr.hovered .sss {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
}

tr.hovered {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: initial !important;
}

.style-button:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

You must make sure in this example all ids are unique. If this cannot be the case, use another unique value.

**Updated**

If you want to have this state not only when your component is being hovered, but generally when active, I would do the following:

Rename the state to "isActive" and pass the value from the subcomponent to the parent so you can use this value on your className. Also, re-add your original styles for when the component is being hovered, in that case you will have the styles both when the component is hovered and while it is active. This is how you would do it:

**App.tsx**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SubMenu } from "./SubMenu";
import { useState } from "react";

const subMenuSlice = <SubMenu />;

const nodes = [
  {
    id: "0",
    name: "Samsung Galaxy",
    subMenu: subMenuSlice
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Iphone",
    subMenu: subMenuSlice
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<string | null>(null);

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {nodes.map((val, key) => (
          <tr key={key} className={isActive === val.id ? "active" : ""}>
            <td>{val.name}</td>
            <td>
              {/* Check if the callback returns true, if so set isActive to the id */}
              <SubMenu
                openCallback={(boolValue) =>
                  boolValue ? setIsActive(val.id) : setIsActive(null)
                }
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.sss {
  visibility: hidden;
}

tr.active .sss, tr:hover .sss {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
}

tr.active, tr:hover {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: initial !important;
}

.style-button:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

**SubMenu.tsx**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import AppsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Apps";
import * as DropdownMenu from "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu";
import "./styles.css";

export const SubMenu = ({ openCallback }: { openCallback?: (arg: boolean) => void }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
    if (openCallback) {
      openCallback(!isOpen); // call the function with the boolean value !isOpen
    }
  };

  return (
    <DropdownMenu.Root open={isOpen} onOpenChange={handleOpen}>
      <DropdownMenu.Trigger>
        <AppsIcon className="sss" />
      </DropdownMenu.Trigger>
      <DropdownMenu.Portal>
        <DropdownMenu.Content
          side="bottom"
          sideOffset={-30}
          align="start"
          alignOffset={80}
        >
          <button className="style-button">Edit </button>
          <button className="style-button">Make </button>
          <button className="style-button">Delete </button>
        </DropdownMenu.Content>
      </DropdownMenu.Portal>
    </DropdownMenu.Root>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. Yes, your answer is almost correct. But there is one nuance: after I opened the submenu and moved the cursor there, the hover remains active. But if I move the cursor outside the submenu, the hover disappears, although the submenu is active. Is it possible to make the hover active while it is active under the menu?

Comment: In that case, I would pass the state from the submenu to the parent component using a callback function. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Yes, it works great, thanks. But let me clarify: I render {val.name} and {val.subMenu} so that each device ID has its own settings.
 
If we use <td> <SubMenu....../> </td> in the second option, will this not be a problem?

Comment: Any data that you need inside <SubMenu .../> can come from your `notes` list (or anywhere else), so this should not matter. Just make sure the settings you need are passed into the component.

Comment: Perhaps you can help me. I'm currently trying to transfer to SubMenu exactly the ID that I want to delete, but it doesn't work. Tell me how to transfer exactly the required ID for further work

Comment: Sounds like you want to do this: https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-componentv

Comment: Sorry, but 'This page doesn’t exist.'

Comment: There was a typo, sorry. This is the right URL: https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

Answer (score 0):

If you're not desperate to support old browsers you can use [:has() CSS relational pseudo-class](https://caniuse.com/css-has) to style the `tr` when it contains a `button` having `data-state="open"`. One big caveat is that this is not yet supported in Firefox. However, at the time of writing, it does have global support of ~87.53%.

So if that's for you, the approach is as follows:

1. Give `.sss` descendent of open buttons a grey bg:

   `tr td button[data-state="open"] .sss {...}`
2. Give `tr` that contains (/'has') an open button a grey bg:

   `tr:has(button[data-state="open"]) {...}`

Your complete style.css looks like this:

```
.sss {
  visibility: hidden;
}

tr:hover .sss,
tr td button[data-state="open"] .sss {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
}

tr:hover,
tr:has(button[data-state="open"]) {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: initial !important;
}

.style-button:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-tess-zcf23k

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. Your code works, but there is one problem. Below I will try to describe the problem: as you understand, my real table has more columns and one column contains a button (Change Color) similar to the SubMenu button, that is, this button appears only when hovering and has className="sss". And for some reason, when applying your solution, when you turn on the submenu, the hover remains, but this button (ChangeColor) disappears (although the SubMenu button does not disappear).
Perhaps you know what to do to eliminate this problem

Comment: @Paul in your sandbox `.sss` is a CHILD of the `button`. Your description above states that your 'change color' button itself has the class `.sss`.  Can you provide an updated example that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<DropdownMenu.Portal>` so content is not pasted into the `body` [portal](https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/dropdown-menu#portal)
I would also add `table { border-spacing: 0; }` that there is no space between the cells.
Here is an example:
[**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-meadow-h3pl53)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, I introduce one.

-App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SubMenu } from "./SubMenu";
import { useState } from "react";

const nodes = [
  {
    id: "0",
    name: "Samsung Galaxy"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Iphone"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const subMenuSlice = (id) => (
    <SubMenu openCallback={(boolValue) => boolValue ? setIsActive(id) : setIsActive(null)} />
  );

  const addSubMenuNodes = nodes.map((node) => ({
    ...node,
    subMenu: subMenuSlice(node.id)
  }));
  //you can modify submenu for each node in nodes.

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {addSubMenuNodes.map((val, key) => (
          <tr key={key} className={isActive === val.id ? "active" : ""}>
            <td>{val.name}</td>
            <td>{val.subMenu}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

-SubMenu.tsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import AppsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Apps";
import * as DropdownMenu from "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu";
import "./styles.css";

export const SubMenu = ({ openCallback }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
    if (openCallback) {
      openCallback(!isOpen); // call the function with the boolean value !isOpen
    }
  };

  return (
    <DropdownMenu.Root open={isOpen} onOpenChange={handleOpen}>
      <DropdownMenu.Trigger>
        <AppsIcon className="sss" />
      </DropdownMenu.Trigger>
      <DropdownMenu.Portal>
        <DropdownMenu.Content
          side="bottom"
          sideOffset={-30}
          align="start"
          alignOffset={80}
        >
          <button className="style-button">Edit </button>
          <button className="style-button">Make </button>
          <button className="style-button">Delete </button>
        </DropdownMenu.Content>
      </DropdownMenu.Portal>
    </DropdownMenu.Root>
  );
};
```

-style.css

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.sss {
  visibility: hidden;
}

tr.active .sss,
tr:hover .sss {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
}

tr.active,
tr:hover {
  background: gray;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: initial !important;
}

.style-button:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

It will work correctly.

I hope my answer can help you.

Good luck.

Oh, If this is ok, please don't forget vote my answer